# Cannot find zipalign

Tags: android, android-studio, ionic-framework, sdk, zipalign

I just installed the latest Android Studio.

I cannot find zipalign anywhere on disk. In fact I cannot find it with search, nor can I find the folders or folder structure described in the [Ionic Docs, here.](https://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/publishing.html)

The crazy thing is - [I wrote a Medium post about this very process!](https://medium.com/@sub_effect/adventures-in-apps-hybrids-for-the-amateur-6ef83cff335a#.baynzzmbc) And I cannot find ***that*** folder structure.

I'm stuck. jarsigner worked but I cannot zipalign and so... I can no longer release apps!

What am I doing wrong?! I feel like I'm losing my mind.

Answer (score 0):

It should be in your `[SDK_DIR]/build_tools/[build tools version]`. At least I have it there.

Comment: Yeah, but I can't find any of this. Why doesn't it show up in search? So silly.

Comment: Do you have built tools [installed](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html)?